# Instant search in django application

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-ajax-selects

I am using django in windows

I am giving a text field to search by name of category, Text box should give me name result like Google instant

By selecting name, it should give me the details of category in the **same page itself**.

Any body can help me out.

Comment: jqueryui has autocomplete plugin http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Without giving a little more information, we're probably not going to be able to help you. What does your code look like right now? What have you tried to do to get this to work?

Comment: I need a kind of result like google when you search for any thing.In my application if I need that type output when we search about the category, there is search by category option here i am going to provide a text box, exactly here i need Active search. What I mean to say, is there anything to do in my model?

Answer (score -1):

Check out [django-ajax-search](https://github.com/side-winder/django-ajax-search) 
It should solve your problem